# C# WPF User interface not getting updated

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I am trying to learn WPF with MVVM and i came across a problem that i can't figure out. I am trying to display 3 lists on a popup window, but i want to insert values into those lists from a MainViewmodel(the lists are in reportviewmodel). The thing is that if i add values from the constructor of reportviewmodel they show up but if i want to add them from the MainViewModel they won't. In the debugger everything works fine, but it;s not showing on the U.I. Thanks

---

XAML

```
 <Popup x:Name="Pop" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=PCheckBox}"
            PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PCheckBox}"           
            AllowsTransparency="True"
            PopupAnimation="Slide"
            HorizontalOffset="450"
            VerticalOffset="-60"
            Margin="0,0,8,8"
```

/>

```
            <Border   BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                <Grid DataContext="{Binding}" Width="300" Height="300" Background="Gainsboro" Margin="0">
                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <RotateTransform x:Name="theTransform" />
                    </Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <Button Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Command="{Binding AbortCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Abort"/>
                    <TreeView>
                        <TreeView.DataContext>
                            <vm:ReportViewModel/>
                        </TreeView.DataContext>
                        <TreeViewItem Header="Error" IsExpanded="True">
                            <ListView>
                                <GridViewColumn  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Error}"/>
                            </ListView>
                        </TreeViewItem>
                        <TreeViewItem Header="Warning" IsExpanded="True">
                            <ListView>
                                <GridViewColumn  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Warning}"/>
                            </ListView>
                        </TreeViewItem>
                        <TreeViewItem Header="Information" IsExpanded="True">

                            <ListView>
                                <GridViewColumn  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Information}"/>
                            </ListView>
                        </TreeViewItem>
                    </TreeView>

                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
```

---

MainViewModel

```
class AdminViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
   private RelayCommand generateCommand;
   public RelayCommand GenerateCommand{    get { return generateCommand; } }    
   public AdminViewModel()
    {
        generateCommand = new RelayCommand(o => { Generate(); });
        abortCommand = new RelayCommand(o => { abort(); });
        rvm = new ReportViewModel(); 
    }
   rvm = new ReportViewModel();
   private ReportViewModel rvm;

   private async void Generate()
   {
       prg = new Progress();
       Text = "starting";
       Step = 15;
       if (CadFilePath == string.Empty) //always true
       {
            rvm.LogError("Warning", "This is a warning");
           IsChecked = true; //for the popup to show
       }
```

---

ReportViewModel

```
 class ReportViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private List<string> error;
    public List<string> Error
    {
        get { return error; }
        set
        {
            error = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Error");
        }
    }
    private List<string> warning;
    public List<string> Warning
    {
        get { return warning; }
        set { warning = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Warning");
        }
    }

    private List<string> information;
    public List<string> Information
    {
        get { return information; }
        set { information = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Information");
        }
    }

    public ReportViewModel()
    {
        error = new List<string>();
        warning = new List<string>();
        information = new List<string>();
        Warning.Add("Warning");
        Warning.Add("Warning2");
        Error.Add("404");
    }

    public void LogError(string severity, string err)
    {
        Warning.Add(err);
        Error.Add(err);
        Information.Add(err);

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set up dynamic bindings so that insertions or deletions in the collection update the UI automatically, the collection must implement the INotifyCollectionChanged interface. This interface exposes the CollectionChanged event, an event that should be raised whenever the underlying collection changes. WPF provides the `ObservableCollection<T>` class, which is a built-in implementation of a data collection that implements the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface.

If you want to bind collections and add or delete elements then use [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1) as an container. It represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

So you need just to replace types of collection in your ViewModel:

```
class ReportViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> error;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Error
    {
        get { return error; }
        set
        {
            error = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Error");
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<string> warning;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Warning
    {
        get { return warning; }
        set { warning = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Warning");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> information;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Information
    {
        get { return information; }
        set { information = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Information");
        }
    }

    public ReportViewModel()
    {
        error = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        warning = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        information = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Warning.Add("Warning");
        Warning.Add("Warning2");
        Error.Add("404");
    }

    public void LogError(string severity, string err)
    {
        Warning.Add(err);
        Error.Add(err);
        Information.Add(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not working if i want to update from AdminViewModel, the DataContext for the popup is set to ReportViewModel but when i press the button the popup appears but the list it's not updated.

Comment: So basically what i'm trying to do is populate the lists from the AdminViewModel and open a new window(at some point in application) which has all the items of the lists loaded.(the new window's dataContext is set to ReportViewModel)